# Node push function names from file into array

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a text file I have a function for each line which looks like this:

```
function1()
function2()
```

Then I'm reading the lines from the file with this:

```
var functionArray = [] as any[];

lineReader.eachLine('test.txt', function(line, last) {

var functionArray.push(line);

    console.log(test)

});
```

This returns this:

```
['function1()','function2()']
```

I need it to return:

```
[function1(),function2()]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `[function1(),function2()]` is not a valid Javascript data structure. (it could be defined as an array literal if those functions are defined beforehand, but that's not the case here)

Comment: Why do you need to return it like that (Although as Certain has pointed out, you can't)? What are you trying to achieve? I can take a guess and say you want to run those functions at some point, but you _can_ with them as strings

Comment: That's correct. I want to run them inside a Promise.all but with the quotes into just returning the string and not the value

Comment: Same as Promise.all([function1(), function2]); but I read the function list from a file

Comment: Depending on where those functions are you can use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to get them, or [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) but bracket notation would be a lot safer, faster and better, so try and find a way to use that over eval.

Comment: How would I use the bracket notation in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on a few other things being right, but you can get it working by removing the `()` and getting the function with the bracket notation.

This is a lot safer than `eval` among other advantages, especially if the text file is something users can upload and run as eval will run anything you pass it, whereas with the bracket notation something will have to have been defined to run in the first place.

```js
var fileArray = ['function1()', 'function2()']

var functionObject = {
  function1: function() {
    console.log('This is function1')
  },
  function2: function() {
    console.log('This is function2')
  }
}

var functionArray = []

fileArray.forEach(function(line) {
  line = line.replace('()', '')
  functionArray.push(functionObject[line]);
});

console.log(functionArray)

functionArray.forEach((f) => {
  f()
})
```

Still, here's how you *could* but probably shouldn't do it with `eval`

```js
var fileArray = ['function1()', 'function2()']

var functionObject = {
  function1: function() {
    console.log('This is function1')
  },
  function2: function() {
    console.log('This is function2')
  }
}

var functionArray = []

fileArray.forEach(function(line) {
  line = line.replace('()', '')
  functionArray.push(line);
});

console.log(functionArray)

functionArray.forEach((f) => {
  eval(f)()
})


function function1() {
  console.log('This is function1')
}

function function2() {
  console.log('This is function2')
}
```

I've had to change some things to make it a runnable snippet, but in the end you get an array of functions which can be run however you like